# MemoryRead<T> only T int, float, string & sizeof(T)?

Tags: c#, memory

Hello I am writing right now Memory class which contains MemoryRead function. I had first MemoryReadInt but when I thought about multiple functions for other types like string float.. are way too many. One code changes need to change on every single function too.

So I thought about types.

But I stuck. This is my main.

```
        Memory m = new Memory("lf2");
        Console.WriteLine("Health: " + m.MemoryRead<int>(0x00458C94, 0x2FC));
        m.CloseMemoryprocess();
```

Now this is the function

```
    public int MemoryRead<T>(int baseAdresse, params int[] offsets)
    {

        if(!ProcessExists())
            return -1;

        uint size = sizeof(T); << this cause the error
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
```

Since I need sizeof because I need to define size of buffer.

Also the return value will change soon to T too. So I don't know what I can do here. I hope you can help me.

Btw I want just use string, int, float for now. Can I limit it to it?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is add another parameter to the method for the size,  you can't constrain to integral types. `sizeof` won't work with all types so there really isn't any constraint you can make that would compile the way you have it. I don't think this is a good candidate for a generic since you only use T for the size.

Comment: The error message you get when trying to do `sizeof(T)` gives you the solution:  'T' does not have a predefined size, therefore sizeof can only be used in an unsafe context (consider using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf). That is, use  `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))`

Comment: @Rob: noting, of course, that `Marshal.SizeOf()` tells you the size of the _marshaled_ type, i.e. as an unmanaged type. This may or may not solve the specific problem here; there's not really enough context to know for sure what's going.

Comment: Let's assume for a moment you could write `sizeof(T)`, and you are able to allocate a `byte[]` of the desired size. How are you going to use that `byte[]`? Without a complete code example, it's hard to know what the best suggestion for your particular scenario might be. You may well run into more trouble later trying to copy the bytes back to a variable of type `T`. Please provide better context so we can provide better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I need to answer my own question. After long research (yesterday.. I needed to sleep first then post :D) I changed my plan.

I am looking for types first.
Then I go to next MemoryRead takes one more uint size. Which also check for types. But if customer uses uint size and T string. so the function knows he wants string back. But string need a size given by the user :D

```
public T MemoryRead<T>(int baseAdresse, params int[] offsets) 
{

    if(!ProcessExists())
        return default(T);

    uint size = 0;

    if(typeof(T) == typeof(int)) {
        size = sizeof(int);
        return (T)(object)MemoryRead<int>(baseAdresse, size, offsets);

    } else if(typeof(T) == typeof(float)) {
        size = sizeof(float);
        return (T)(object)MemoryRead<float>(baseAdresse, size, offsets);

    } else if(typeof(T) == typeof(double)) {
        size = sizeof(double);
        return (T)(object)MemoryRead<double>(baseAdresse, size, offsets);

    }else {

        MessageBox.Show("Wrong type. Maybe you want to use MemoryRead<string>(int, uint, params [] int)", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        throw new ArgumentException("Wrong type. Maybe you want to use MemoryRead<string>(int, uint, params [] int)");

    }
}
```

Alternative I can do also this: Because the overloaded function takes uint.. and users can forget it to cast to uint and use int.. this would just fill the params:

```
    public int MemoryReadInt(int baseAdresse, params int[] offsets)
    {
        return MemoryRead<int>(baseAdresse, sizeof(int), offsets);
    }

    public string MemoryReadString(int baseAdresse, uint readSize, params int[] offsets)
    {
        return MemoryRead<string>(baseAdresse, readSize, offsets);
    }
```